# AWS Boto3 copy files to s3 with different clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to copy files from one s3 bucket in one AWS account to another S3 bucket to another S3 account, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

It will be something like this:

```
def init_s3_bucket(aws_key_id, aws_secret_key, bucket_name):
    s3_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=aws_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key
    )

    s3_resource = s3_session.resource('s3', verify=False)
    return s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)


aa_s3_bucket = init_s3_bucket(aws_access_key_id='aa',
                              aws_secret_access_key='aa',
                              bucket_name='s3bb')


bb_s3_bucket = init_s3_bucket(aws_access_key_id='bb',
                              aws_secret_access_key='bb',
                              bucket_name='s3bb')

for file_origin in aa_s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="aa"):
     copy_source = {'Bucket': aa_s3_bucket.name,
                   'Key': file_origin.key}
     bb_s3_bucket.copy(copy_source, file_origin.key)
```

Because the bb S3 bucket has no access to aa bucket, I cannot copy those files.
I tried to do the same with boto3.client instead of sessions without luck either.

Any help is welcomed. Thank you in advance to everyone.

Comment: Have you set up a role you are allowed to use in the second account from the first account? This is needed and when use sts.assumerole() this will generate credentials you can use in the client not connected to the account you are running the function in.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you may have to copy locally the files (first download then upload).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ErikAsplund. So what you are proposing is to give permissions to access s3 A to the account B. If they are in the same account, you assume the role for access, if not, you need cross account access. The problem is it need to touch infrastructure setup.
I was wondering if it was any way to copy by using the two clients.

Comment: You can use a client with access keys for the target account. The way you think about access from bucket aa to bucket bb sound wrong in my head. Think more lambda/user running script need access to both bucket aa and bucket bb to do this.

Comment: Finally I gave access to the client bb to the bucket of aa, because I couldn't find any solution. Thank you to both @ErikAsplund #floh